# Ember.js each-in helper not found

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember.js 1.13.10

I get an Assertion Error helper 'each-in' could not be found

I searched the code in my bower component and indeed the each-in helper is not in the codebase

I don't understand why it is not there, it is in both the [1.13](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/) and [2.0](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/) guides and as far as I know ember 1.13 is identical to 2.0 minus the depreciations. each-in is a new feature which I can see on the github repo.

**Update**

submitted [an issue](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/issues/811) turns out each-in was a added incorrectly in the 1.13 guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `each-in` helper has been added in Ember v2.0.0 beta. You can read about it in [EMBER.JS 1.13.0 AND 2.0 BETA RELEASED blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_ember-2-0-beta).

In this blog post, [section about `each-in` helper](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_each-in-helper) is under `EMBER 2.0 BETA`.

You could probably submit pull request to Ember guides to remove mentions of `each-in` helper from 1.13 guides if it is indeed present.

So, to sum sup -`each-in` helper was introduced in v2.0.0 beta and it isn't present in v1.13 source - [should be each-in path](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/release-1-13/packages/ember-htmlbars/lib/helpers/each-in.js). It also can't be enabled by feature flag, because [no such feature flag present](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/release-1-13/FEATURES.md).

Comment: I will submit a pull request, tho that said is there an alternative to using something similar in 1.13

Comment: Nevermind, Wrote a simple component to do the job taking an object and breaking it down into an array of key value then in the template running each with {{yield key value}}

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of `each-in` an `get` in the 1.13 was an oversight of the documentation team when cutting the deploy. You can track our fixing it at https://github.com/emberjs/guides/issues/811.